# Can an academic paper be published about vulnerabilities found in a bug bounty?

Tags: publications, research-process, conference, paper-submission, research-topic

Most papers I have read have some theoretical aspect to it, involving some sort of a pseudocode. I'm into vulnerability analysis and penetration testing and I actively indulge in bug bounty programs. Can I publish a paper about the vulnerabilities I found in a bug bounty?

Comment: This question depends on the content of your research, and the rules of the bug bounty.  We can't answer it without seeing the exact bug.  Even if you post that, it will be off-topic.

Comment: Papers are all about new ideas. When you found a new type of vulnerability or way to discover and/or mitigate one, that's a paper. However, there are also specialized publication venues for papers on applications of existing methods to new systems.

Answer (score 2):

I would say Yes, depending;

- Is it an interesting new type of vulnerability?
- Did you use an interesting new method to find it?
- Do you have interesting new insights about this kind of (already known) vulnerability, perhaps linking it to a different concept?
- Can you take the actions you took to find specific vulnerabilities in specific cases,  and generalize them to a broader methodology?
- Can you compare the effectiveness of two different methods to detect a particular vulnerability?
- Do you have a testbench of vulnerable setups that can be used to evaluate new detection tools?

Or similar things. The key aspect is *novelty*. What are you telling experts that they don't already know?

Apart from wholly original ideas, there's also the class of papers known as Survey Papers. These collect a range of existing studies and give an overview and analysis of the state of the field of research. In this case, you could do a survey of what the current state is of research into particular types of vulnerabilities.